# How can chips inside a disabled v-select be made clickable?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-select` that is representing the selected items with `v-chip`s internally. I want the chips to be used as buttons when the user is not editing the selection, however the `v-select` is disabled when the user is not editing the selection. Since the `v-select` is disabled, none of the `@click` events I bind to the `v-chip` work, since the disable behavior cascades down to the `v-chip`s. Since the `v-select` needs to be disabled to prevent the dropdown behavior, how can I enable my `@click` events on the `v-chip` elements.

See this CodePen for my rough setup: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/orLxMz

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `disable` property of the `v-select` adds a

```css
pointer-events: none;
```

style to all of its descendants. This is what is preventing the `@click` events from firing.

To re-enable the `v-chip`s for clicking, add the style

```css
pointer-events: all;
```

to the v-chip declaration.

See this working CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXEKLN